# GatsbyJs, page inside folder

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

i read that gatsby create the proper page if you save items in the pages folder.

Ex---->

```
src/
  pages/
    Home.tsx
    LandingPage.tsx
```

I can reach the page, for example at http://localhost:8000/LandingPage

but what can i do if I have the following folder structure ?

```
src/
  pages/
    Home/
      index.tsx
    LandingPage/
      index.tsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following folder structure:

```
src/
  pages/
    Home/
      index.tsx
    LandingPage/
      index.tsx
```

You will get the following paths:

http://localhost:8000/Home

http://localhost:8000/LandingPage

You don't have to set anything else Gatsby figures it out for you by default.